# Car starts in park and drive only and stuck in 4lo

Tags: 4l60e

I have a 2000 GMC Jimmy SLE with 4wheel auto 2hi 4hi and 4lo options on dash. It will start in park and drive but not neutral. Would not shift into 4 wheel at all and I found out a vaccum hose was not hooked up so I hooked it back up and tested it by pressing my 4lo button. It shifted so I thought it was fixed but now it wont shift out of 4lo no matter what I do. Also my reverse lights come on in neutral but not reverse. I'm 100% positive it's the neutral safety switch. My questions are: is there any way to force it out of 4lo and is it possible the switch could just be cockeyed and just needs to be adjusted or will I need to replace the whole thing?

Comment: Have you checked that the selector mechanism has not slipped or been damaged?

Comment: Is that the buttons inside the vehicle?

Comment: No not the buttons, the selector mechanism.

Comment: The actuator under the battery? Or the one on the t-case?

Comment: NO, the selector mechanism between the gear selector and the gearbox...

Comment: No I haven't. How do I go about checking this?

Comment: *update* 4 wheel drive fixed itself